# Launching composed task built by DSL from stream application

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Every example I've seen (`task-launcher` sink and `triggertask` source ) shows how to launch  the task defined by **uri** attribute. 
My tasks definitions look like this :

```
sampleTask  <t2: timestamp || t1: timestamp> 
sampleTask-t1   timestamp   
sampleTask-t2   timestamp   
sampleTaskRunner    composed-task-runner --graph=sampleTask
```

My question is how do I launch the composed task runner (`sampleTaskRunner`, defined by DSL) from stream application.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I ended up with the below solution that triggers task using SCDF REST API :

`composedTask` definition :

`<timestamp || mySampleTask>`

Stream definition :

`http | httpclient | log`

Deployment  properties :

```
app.http.port=81
app.httpclient.body=name=composedTask&arguments=--increment-instance-enabled=true
app.httpclient.http-method=POST
app.httpclient.url=http://localhost:9393/tasks/executions
app.httpclient.headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Though it's easy to implement `http sink` component, would  be great if stream application starters will provide one out of the box.

Another concern I have is about discovering the SCDF REST URL when deployed in distributed environment.

Comment: Your solution assumes there will be an HTTP event that will launch the composed-task - is that true? Just for clarification: If the goal is to simply trigger the launch of the composed-task, you have 2 options. 1) Use the `trigger-source` stream definition listed in the answer 2) Use an external scheduler that can schedule (via webhooks) the composed-task REST endpoint

Comment: My goal is to invoke the composed  task on demand, the source could be http / destination channel/ect. I'm not sure what you mean by `external scheduler that can schedule (via **webhooks**) the composed-task REST endpoint`

Comment: OK, great, if there's real need to react to an upstream event such as a data/trigger coming from the `http-source`, sure, what you have would work. You could also use the `task-launcher-local` or the platform-specific sink to launch it instead of `http-client`. There are options.

Comment: As for the external scheduler, there are tools that can schedule the trigger of REST endpoints via webhooks. Here's an [example](https://medium.com/iron-io-blog/scheduled-webhooks-aka-cron-for-the-cloud-e298be33cc3c).

Comment: Thank, I'am after triggering the task `BY NAME`, not by passing the `--graph` argument. The  only option I've found is via SCDF REST API, all others (`trigger-task` source  and `task-request-transform` processor will require `--graph` attribute be specified and I wan to decouple invocation and definition )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick take from one of the SCDF's R&D team members (Glenn Renfro).

> stream create foozer --definition "trigger --fixed-delay=5 | tasklaunchrequest-transform --uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:composedtaskrunner-task:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT --command-line-arguments=**'--graph=sampleTask-t1||sampleTask-t2 --increment-instance-enabled=true --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=password --spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'** | task-launcher-local" --deploy

In the `foozer` stream definition,

1) "trigger" source happens to trigger an upstream event every 5s

2) "tasklaunchrequest-transform" processor takes a few arguments; more specifically, it uses "composedtaskrunner-task:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" to launch a composed-task graph (i.e., `sampleTask-t1||sampleTask-t2`)

3) Pay attention to `--increment-instance-enabled`. This was [recently added](https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/issues/9) to CTR application and this provides the ability to re-launch a composed-task in a recurring cadence

4) Since the CTR and SCDF must [share the same database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuring_the_composed_task_runner_2), we are also passing datasource properties as command-line args. (SCDF-server is already started with the same datasource credentials)

Hope this helps.

Lastly, we will add a sample to the reference guide via: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#1780](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1780)

Comment: Thanks, but can I pass graph as composed task name which itself is defined as `sampleTask-t1||sampleTask-t2`?

Comment: No, a graph is a DSL representation of "task definitions", so the assumption in the above example is that you've already created a composed-task graph. In your example, it will be something like: `task create sampleTask --definition "<t2: timestamp || t1: timestamp>`. This will create `sampleTask-t1`  and `sampleTask-t2` task definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase the question :  `task create sampleTask --definition "<t2: timestamp || t1: timestamp>` and then `.....  tasklaunchrequest-transform --uri=maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:composedtaskrunner-task:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT --command-line-arguments=--graph=sampleTask.... `. Is this supported?

Comment: You're combing task and stream DSL together, no it is not meant to be used that way. Of course, you will see an error when you try it. You must have task definitions created beforehand and then use the trigger-source to orchestrate a streaming launch on a specific interval. If you intend to schedule a composed-task directly; perhaps it'd be better that you use a scheduler tool that schedules for webhooks. SCDF exposed REST-APIs for the composed tasks, so you can add a webhook to launch the composed-task from an external scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, @SabbyAnandan, I've updated my question with your proposal, is this what you meant ?